# svnadmin create -- Error?

Tags: svn, svnadmin, collabnet

ok I installed the subversion binary from collabnet onto my win7 computer.

when I ran the installed it put the main files in:

> C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server

it also create an empty directory for my repositories here:

> C:\svn_repository

I opened up a cmd.exe and rain this line:

> C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion
>   Server>svnadmin create /var/svn/repos

it gave me this error:

> Repository creation failed
>   Could not create top-level directory
>   The system could not find the path specified

After research I found that the file path `/var/svn/repos` has to already exist. but WHERE?

I tried add this file path to `C:\svn_repository` making it `C:\svn_repository\var\svn\repos` I also tried adding the path to `C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server`

still get the same error everytime I run:

> C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion
>   Server>svnadmin create /var/svn/repos

I also tried making the slashes backwards like:

> C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion
>   Server>svnadmin create \var\svn\repos

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `/var/svn/repos` is itself a (Unix-style) path, and doesn't exist. Considering that you're on Windows, you probably want something like this instead:

`svnadmin create C:\svn_repository\newrepository`

(If that fails, try creating the directory manually first: `mkdir C:\svn_repository\newrepository` and then the command above.)

Comment: An aside: You may prefer to use TortoiseSVN instead of the command line. With TortoiseSVN, it's simply a matter of right-clicking on a directory and choosing "Create Repository Here".  Of course, learning the command line is a good idea in any case, but for the infrequent requirements (creating repositories, etc), a GUI is often helpful.